# Error in web.config file

Tags: asp.net

I have developed my final year project in asp.net .
First the error was to remove 'targetFramework' attribute from my web.config file. Then I removed that attribute but now it has given a new error.

[image]

The following information can be
helpful to determine why the assembly
'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
could not be loaded.
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry
value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
(DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with
assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM
\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]

This is the error I am getting. Please help

Comment: Where does that link go to? I don't want to try. Please past relevant code here.

Comment: *"..First the error was to remove 'targetFramework.."* ??

Comment: Try install this:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6576 or the appropriate version

Comment: You could have just copied the message, but I've updated your post, removed the live link and posted a screenshot of your error. Anyway looks like by removing the 'targetFramework' you broke your dependencies. Restore it back, if you need to change your framework do it from project settings, and make sure you deploy all your dlls.

Comment: how do you run the application?

Comment: @abhitalks.. My original web.config file has <compilation targetFramework="4.0">.. And the error was that you should remove that attribute,which i did.. Now it shows this error

Comment: @Davide.. I have registered in a web hosting site.. Then I am getting this error

Comment: @Fedor.. Thanks for the screenshot. And will do it what you told..

Answer (score 0):

If your web application works on your local machine, then the problem is that the ReportViewer dll is not copied to the webserver. You can fix this by setting 'Copy Local' to true (right-click the reference to the ReportViewer.Webforms dll in your web project to view the properties where you can find this setting)

Comment: Actually I am not using this locally.. I have registered in a web hosting site. And then I am getting that error...

Comment: That's exactly my point ;-) Copy Local means the dll is copied to the bin folder of your application, so it will also be copied to your web server.